# Can't use Swift Package Manager with my library

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift-package-manager

I have an open source Swift camera framework called [Lumina](https://github.com/dokun1/Lumina), and I would like to be able to use it with all three main iOS dependency management systems. (Cocoapods and Carthage work fine.)

All of my tags follow semantic versioning rules, but the titles have the letter "v" before them, like so:

[image: list of tags for Lumina]

For the library, the manifest `Package.swift` file reads like so:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Lumina")
```

In another project, I wanted to test that SPM works and uses the latest version of my framework (currently v0.8.4). I created a Single View Application in Xcode 9.0 from scratch, and added the following `Package.swift` file to the root directory:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SwiftPMLumina",
    targets: [],
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/dokun1/Lumina.git", majorVersion: 0, minor: 8)
    ]
)
```

When I do this, the CLI says `error: unsatisfiable` I have also tried not specifying a minor version, and specifying a specific version string (such as `"v0.8.4"`) to no avail.

What do I have to do to properly build this library with SwiftPM, and/or what support do I have to add to the library itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add tags without initial "v" to your framework, like "0.8.4".

Comment: Thank you! Just an FYI to anyone else reading, SPM now locates this package properly, but because my framework requires UIKit, SPM will not properly build the framework.